# How can I check when a user changes the value of a select drop down list?

Tags: jquery

I use the following code to check for a change in value of input fields. In this case fields starting with IDs "Status_" and "Position_"

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[id^='Status_'], input[id^='Position_']").change(function (e) {
        var type = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[0];
        update($(this), type);
    }); 
});
```

Now I have changed from status being an input field to being a selectable dropdown.

```
<select id="Status_0" name="AdminSummaries[0].Status"><option value="1">Released</option>
<option value="2">Review</option>
<option value="3">New</option>
</select>;
```

Now can I make it so that when a new value is selected in the drop down then the update(..) function gets called just like it did if it was an input field?

Comment: Have you tried it?  It should work for you.

Comment: If it doesn't work, the problem is within the `update()` method, please post its code and we'll see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is good. But you may have to change `input[id^='Status_']` to `select[id^='Status_']`.

Comment: or to `:input`, which is a selector for any kind of input (input, textarea, select...)

Answer (score 1):

change `input` to `select`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select[id^='Status_'], input[id^='Position_']").on('change',function (e) {
        var type = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[0];
        update($(this), type);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) available in jQuery and bind it to the dropdown. So the code you posted should still work.

EDIT:
As wescrow pointed out, the problem is not in the use of the change event, but in the selectors used.